# Chain node & java commands in Docker CMD

Tags: java, node.js, docker, cmd

I am trying to execute the following in my container:

```
CMD ["java", "-version", "&&", "node", "index.js"]
```

The first command runs, but the node command does not.  Is the proper syntax for chaining these commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the `exec` form, this means that no shell (sh,bash etc.) is invoked, so what is essentially happening is that `java` gets `"&&"`, `"node"` and `"index.js"` as extra arguments which it will likely ignore.

You can use the shell format to get the logic you want:

```
CMD java -version && node index.js
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining why I am using exec mode in this case?  Is this because I placed my commands in `[]`?  If I were to simply run `CMD java...` without `[]` that would mean I am in shell form, correct?

Comment: yes, that is the case. More info here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd

Comment: Aha, so in exec mode it becomes JSON.  Very interesting.  Thank you.